# Finding where an object is access/modification

Tags: c++, eclipse

I looking for something similar to call hierarchy for functions and type hierarchy for classes but for understanding how an object is accessed and modified. For example, consider the following:

```
1    void F(int x, int &y, int* z) {
2      int a = y;
3      a++;
4      x++;
5      y++;
6      int* b = z;
7      int &c = *b;
8      c++;
9    }

10    int main() {
11      int x0 = 5;
12      int y0 = 9;
13      int z0 = 13;
14      F(x0, y0, &z0);
15      return 0;
16    }
```

I want to get something similar to the following:

- x0 is modified in 11 and accessed in 11 and 14.
- y0 is modified in 5, 12, 14 and accessed in 1, 2, 5, 12, 14.
- z0 is modified in 8, 13, 14 and accessed in 1, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14.

Is there an Eclipse feature or plugin for this?

Comment: I think you want to do a hardware breakpoint or memory breakpoint type thing. If you search that it would probably help. Or you could create a template class to wrap primitives and set breakpoints in the overloaded operators and look at the call stack...?

Comment: @scaryrawr, That is a nice idea, but the problem is it will catch only those which will be executed in test runs. I am hoping like the call hierarchy feature in Eclipse which syntactically analyzes the code.

Comment: Static analysis might be more easier. Simply delete the declaration or make declaration a const and see how it compiles.